# Как определяется каким должно быть окно скользящей средней для временного ряда?

Tags: python-3.x

Я понял, как вычислить простую скользящую среднюю, но не понимаю, как выбирать размер окна. Данные у меня - это электрокардиосигнал за определенный промежуток времени.

Comment: Выбирать такой размер, чтобы не смазывались важные/характерные для кардиограмм особенности.

Comment: @MBo его нужно выбирать в милисекундах или в количестве точек, которые смогут попасть в окно?

Comment: Фактически разницы нет, ведь наверняка отсчёты идут равномерно по времени. Выбранное окно по времени соответствует определённому размеру в количеств точек.